# IOS UIImage data differ with android image (for image downloaded from google)

Tags: android, ios, image, md5, checksum

I am suppose to create a checksum with MD5 Hash generator, and i am using the image [***"Image to create checksum"***](http://autochunk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/youwall-black-sport-car-wallpaper-wallpaper-wallpapers-free.jpg)

I have downloaded an image on both iOS and Andriod device and created MD5 hash as follows:

For Andriod Device:

Checksum : 09955F4875C8798FFEAF5EFD95FB3AA7

Image :

[image]

For IOS Device:

Checksum : 8C18C548188D68C086691BAC7C68DC35

Image :

[image]

I have even cross checked creating checksum by downloading image on system as well which also gives ***"09955F4875C8798FFEAF5EFD95FB3AA7"*** which is matching with the android hash(checksum).

When i download the image on iOS Device its resolution might be getting change, so how to overcome this problem ?can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue ? i need to match the checksum for both android and iOS.

Comment: 1. The image data you are generation the md5 hash from is different, start by checking the length and data format that is being hashed. 2. Present a smaller problem that can be checked by those interested in answering the question, as it is there is no way to answer. 3. md5 does not produce a "Checksum", it produces a hash. 4. md5 should not be used for new work, use a SHA* hash function.

Comment: Ok actually my problem is the hash which is created from IOS device is giving different result from the result which is being created from the online hash generator.

Comment: The iOS Common Crypto functions work correctly, that is the only answer that is available for the question as asked. If incorrect data is provided to the md5 function the output will not be as expected. There still is not enough information to answer the question. There is no code, no information about the function being used to create the hash. No information about the representation of the data.

Comment: but the issue is with image data, when i am downloading any image from safari and saving it in image gallery on ios device, maybe its getting converted to png format(not sure), where as the actual image is of jpeg format.